# Django Error during template rendering no such column

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I was trying to show the list of the User's to-do lists using `view.html`. The error says:

> no such column:testapp_todolist.user_id".

But I don't understand where this column is and how it is related to the red line in my `view.html`:

```
{% for td in user.todolist.all %}
```

Can you please explain in details how do I add this column?

Here's my `models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class ToDoList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="todolist", default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Item(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `user.todolist_set.all`

Answer (score 1):

Try solving this by writing this on your console:

- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate`

Those commands are going to create tables for the TodoList model in the database.

Answer (score 0):

user does not have the object todolist, todolist is a foreign key in Item. You should do:

```
list = ToDoList.objects.filter(user=YOUR_USER_HERE)
```

or

```
# if you want to get the todolist of the currently logged in user
list = ToDoList.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```